# Global css variables in Angular library project

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, global-variables, angular-library

I want to use global css vars in an Angular lib project like i do in normal projects:

Declare all variables in root scope in `global.scss` file

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: #FF0000;
}
```

And then, in any component:

```css
p {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

`global.scss` is loaded in angular.json assets array but in library project this won't work.
I've tried loading `global.scss` file from `ng-package.json` file in lib -> styleIncludePaths but it's not working at all [(documentation)](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/style-include-paths.md).